# Recursive function to search find and change specific cells based on a criteria

Tags: c, recursion

I'm trying in C to write a recursive function that takes as an input an NxM matrix, and finds, checks specific cells and changes their content based on a scenario.

[Original matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUaZY.jpg)

The matrix elements are:

```
   1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
------------------
1| 1 6 7 4 4 1 2 8
2| 1 3 6 3 3 1 3 4
3| 3 4 1 5 7 8 5 1
4| 1 7 8 6 2 6 4 4
5| 7 8 1 6 2 2 7 1
6| 3 8 4 3 1 6 8 6
7| 3 8 7 5 4 6 6 6
8| 7 2 2 1 7 4 6 8
```

Based on a matrix like the above, a user gives the location of a specific cell, e.g. position (5,6) for the integer 2. I want the recursive function to check the cells in the four directions, up, down, left, right and if it finds the same integer to change them to 0s. This will continue for all the "neighborhood"  cells. In this example all twos at positions (5,6), (5,5) and (4,5) will change to 0s.

Another example:
user gives location i.e. position (8,7) for the integer 6. The recursive function has to find and change all 6s at the positions (8,7), (7,7), (7,8), (7,6), (6,6), (6,8) and set them to 0s.

```
    void destroy(int (*arr), int rows, int cols,int search,int rowin, int colin) //rows: total rows of matrxi, cols:total cols of matrix, rowin and colin are the x,y co ordinates of the cell that the user wants to destroy and search has the int i.e 6 ..
{
    int i, j;

    printf("\n");
    printf("\n");

    int count = 0,temp = 0;

    for (j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {

          if (*(arr + i*cols + j)== search) {
          if (*(arr + (i-1)*cols + j) == search){//check neighborhood cell
            count++; //counter to know how many similar neighborhood integers have been found
            (*(arr + i*cols + j)= 0);
            *(arr + (i-1)*cols + j) = 0;    
            destroy(int (*arr), int rows, int cols,int search, j, i)   //call recursive function to check the neighborhood cells of the new position  i,j           

        }

      }     
}
}
}
```

Comment: In the function argument list, `int (*arr)` is identical in meaning to `int *arr`.  As long as you know that, there's no particular harm done.  If, however, you think it means something else, that's a problem.

Comment: You should not use keyword i.e break as a function name.

Comment: @Tan_007 — you beat me to it, but the prohibition is stronger than "should"; you **cannot** use a keyword as an identifier.

Comment: @Tan_007 yes you are right!!TY! I changed it to destroy! :)

Comment: Don't post links to pictures of what could be presented as text — such as the 8x8 matrix.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I did it to show exactly how the whole matrix is... :)

Comment: It took me less than 5 minutes to generate the text equivalent to the image.  Note that the matrix diagram counts from index 1; C matrices count from index 0.  You'll need to account for that rather crucial difference somewhere along the line.  You should probably remove the two `printf()` statements in the function.  If you retained any printing, you could combine those into `printf("\n\n");`.

Comment: `destroy(int (*arr), j, i,int search)` --> `destroy(arr, j, i,search)`

Comment: @JonathanLeffler OK I removed the printfs completely...

Comment: Note that you never use the `colin` or `rowin` parameters, which is problematic.  Either you don't need the parameters and should eliminate them, or you need to use them and there's a major bug in your code.  (I think that's what [ARK Niazi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3481412/ark-niazi) is saying in their [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56106992/15168), which isn't really a complete answer.

Comment: Unrelated to most of this, `printf(". ", *(arr + i*cols + j)); ` is broken. There is no format specifier for the argument you're providing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that in C an array index starts from zero (not one).

Here is an example that uses a matrix (aka array of array).

```
#include <stdio.h>

void destroy(int value, int r, int c, int r_size, int c_size, int arr[][r_size])
{
    if (value != arr[r][c]) return;  // Nothing to do
    arr[r][c] = 0;
    if (r+1 < r_size) destroy(value, r+1, c, r_size, c_size, arr); // DOWN
    if (r-1 >= 0) destroy(value, r-1, c, r_size, c_size, arr);     // UP
    if (c+1 < c_size) destroy(value, r, c+1, r_size, c_size, arr); // RIGHT
    if (c-1 >= 0) destroy(value, r, c-1, r_size, c_size, arr);     // LEFT
}


void pm(int r_size, int c_size, int arr[r_size][r_size])
{
    printf("-------------------------------------------\n");
    for (int r=0; r < r_size; ++r)
    {
        for (int c=0; c < c_size; ++c)
        {
            printf("%d ", arr[r][c]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
#define MSIZE 8

int main(void) {
    int arr[MSIZE][MSIZE] =
    {
        {1, 6, 7, 4, 4, 1, 2, 8},
        {1, 3, 6, 3, 3, 1, 3, 4},
        {3, 4, 1, 5, 7, 8, 5, 1},
        {1, 7, 8, 6, 2, 6, 4, 4},
        {7, 8, 1, 6, 2, 2, 7, 1},
        {3, 8, 4, 3, 1, 6, 8, 6},
        {3, 8, 7, 5, 4, 6, 6, 6},
        {7, 2, 2, 1, 7, 4, 6, 8}
    };

    pm(MSIZE, MSIZE, arr);
    destroy(arr[7][6], 7, 6, MSIZE, MSIZE, arr);
    pm(MSIZE, MSIZE, arr);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
-------------------------------------------
1 6 7 4 4 1 2 8 
1 3 6 3 3 1 3 4 
3 4 1 5 7 8 5 1 
1 7 8 6 2 6 4 4 
7 8 1 6 2 2 7 1 
3 8 4 3 1 6 8 6 
3 8 7 5 4 6 6 6 
7 2 2 1 7 4 6 8 
-------------------------------------------
1 6 7 4 4 1 2 8 
1 3 6 3 3 1 3 4 
3 4 1 5 7 8 5 1 
1 7 8 6 2 6 4 4 
7 8 1 6 2 2 7 1 
3 8 4 3 1 0 8 0 
3 8 7 5 4 0 0 0 
7 2 2 1 7 4 0 8
```

**Version 2**

This version a little different because it only changes elements if at least one neighbor is found. Also it counts the number of changes.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int destroy_rec(int value, int r, int c, int r_size, int c_size, int arr[][r_size])
{
    if (value != arr[r][c]) return 0;  // Nothing to do
    int changed = 1;
    arr[r][c] = 0;
    if (r+1 < r_size) changed += destroy_rec(value, r+1, c, r_size, c_size, arr); // DOWN
    if (r-1 >= 0) changed += destroy_rec(value, r-1, c, r_size, c_size, arr);     // UP
    if (c+1 < c_size) changed += destroy_rec(value, r, c+1, r_size, c_size, arr); // RIGHT
    if (c-1 >= 0) changed += destroy_rec(value, r, c-1, r_size, c_size, arr);     // LEFT
    return changed;
}

int destroy(int r, int c, int r_size, int c_size, int arr[][r_size])
{
    if (r+1 < r_size && arr[r+1][c] == arr[r][c]) return destroy_rec(arr[r][c], r, c, r_size, c_size, arr);
    if (r-1 >= 0 && arr[r-1][c] == arr[r][c]) return destroy_rec(arr[r][c], r, c, r_size, c_size, arr);
    if (c+1 < c_size && arr[r][c+1] == arr[r][c]) return destroy_rec(arr[r][c], r, c, r_size, c_size, arr);
    if (c-1 >= 0 && arr[r][c-1] == arr[r][c]) return destroy_rec(arr[r][c], r, c, r_size, c_size, arr);
    return 0;
}

void pm(int r_size, int c_size, int arr[r_size][r_size])
{
    printf("-------------------------------------------\n");
    for (int r=0; r < r_size; ++r)
    {
        for (int c=0; c < c_size; ++c)
        {
            printf("%d ", arr[r][c]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("-------------------------------------------\n");
}
#define MSIZE 8

int main(void) {
    int arr[MSIZE][MSIZE] =
    {
        {1, 6, 7, 4, 4, 1, 2, 8},
        {1, 3, 6, 3, 3, 1, 3, 4},
        {3, 4, 1, 5, 7, 8, 5, 1},
        {1, 7, 8, 6, 2, 6, 4, 4},
        {7, 8, 1, 6, 2, 2, 7, 1},
        {3, 8, 4, 3, 1, 6, 8, 6},
        {3, 8, 7, 5, 4, 6, 6, 6},
        {7, 2, 2, 1, 7, 4, 6, 8}
    };

    pm(MSIZE, MSIZE, arr);
    int changed = destroy(7, 6, MSIZE, MSIZE, arr);
    printf("%d cells changed\n", changed);
    pm(MSIZE, MSIZE, arr);

    int (*dyn_arr)[MSIZE] = malloc(MSIZE * sizeof *dyn_arr);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
-------------------------------------------
1 6 7 4 4 1 2 8 
1 3 6 3 3 1 3 4 
3 4 1 5 7 8 5 1 
1 7 8 6 2 6 4 4 
7 8 1 6 2 2 7 1 
3 8 4 3 1 6 8 6 
3 8 7 5 4 6 6 6 
7 2 2 1 7 4 6 8 
-------------------------------------------
6 cells changed
-------------------------------------------
1 6 7 4 4 1 2 8 
1 3 6 3 3 1 3 4 
3 4 1 5 7 8 5 1 
1 7 8 6 2 6 4 4 
7 8 1 6 2 2 7 1 
3 8 4 3 1 0 8 0 
3 8 7 5 4 0 0 0 
7 2 2 1 7 4 0 8 
-------------------------------------------
```

Comment: I run your code in my DEV C++ compiler and it gave me almost 20 error messages like  [Error] use of parameter outside function body before ']' [Error] 'value' was not declared in this scope 8 [Error] 'arr' was not declared in this scope and many more

Comment: @Mike Are you sure you made a 100% copy? I get a clean compile on my system. You can also see it here https://ideone.com/YSpF09

Comment: I downloaded your file. I compiled it again at my DEV compiler and it gave me these errors in function pm: [Error] 'for' loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 or C11 mode   [Error] 'for' loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 or C11 mode at lines 17 and 19 ....

Comment: @Mike: Try this change: `for (int r=0; r < r_size; ++r)` ==> `int r; for (r=0; r < r_size; ++r)` and the same for the other for-loop. In some old versions of C the variable definition can't be inside the loop. Or better... switch to a newer language version.

Comment: I run it for destroy(arr[5][2], 5, 2, MSIZE, MSIZE, arr); and it changed the cell 5,2 to 0 . It shouldn't change anything because there are no similar neighborhood cells.  For some reason the  if (value != arr[r][c]) return;  // Nothing to do   didn't work.

Comment: @Mike The current version of the program change the starting cell to zero. It was my impression that it should do that.

Comment: also can you put somewhere a counter to know how many changes have been made? For the previous example with the sixes the counter should be 6 because 6 digits changed values.

Comment: 4386427 I wrote in the description , "if it finds the same integer to change THEM to 0s" . This is what I meant... Maybe I should clarify it better..! :) I should add, otherwise, do not change anything

Comment: @Mike ok - well it's a bit unclear to me what you want. Is this it? Case A) No neighbors ==> No change Case B) One or more neighbors ==> Change the start cell to zero and change all neighbors (and their neighbors) to zero.

Comment: @Mike See version 2

Comment: 4386427 Thank you!!! You are top!!! But you made the code hard for me to understand at the version 2... Version 1 was fine... Can't we just add a check at the top of version 1, to see if there are similar neighbors. changed =0 Case A: If there aren't neighbors do nothing changed=0 . If there are neighbors every time the function calls itself increase the counter by 1 so changed = ...

Comment: @Mike In programming there are typically many ways to solve a problem. Your approach may work as well - give it a try. The reason I did like this in version 2 is that it's only the first time you need a check for neighbors. All the recursive calls don't need that check so I found it easy to split it into two functions.

Comment: 4386427. I did it but it returns me for the case of 6s at position 7,6      counter = 25

Comment: @Mike I think the code you have now is far from the posted code. So I'll suggest that you considered this question solved and ask a new question where you post your current code.

Comment: 4386427. I pasted it above so that you can see it...If I ask a new question I will have to explain the same again again ... Can you see what I tried and do small changes to your version 1 and I will paste again the original code of mine at the top after your turn. TY !!!!

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `for` loops but four recursive calls to check each neighborhood.

```
   void destroy(int *arr, int rows, int cols,int search,int rowin, int colin)
    {
         if (rowin>=rows || colin >= cols || rowin < 0 || colin <0) 
             return; //base condition

         if (arr[rowin*cols+colin] == search)
         {
              arr[rowin*cols+colin] = 0;
              destroy(arr, rows, cols, search, rowin+1, colin);
              destroy(arr,  rows, cols, search, rowin, colin+1);
              destroy(arr,  rows, cols, search, rowin-1, colin);
              destroy(arr,  rows, cols, search, rowin, colin-1);

         }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you want to achieve with this because in your code you're already traversing through whole array and after checking one element you want to traverse again. 
In my point of view you don't need another iteration to remove the elements. You can perform this in a single iteration.
If the element you're searching exists then remove the neighbor elements 
`(i,j => (i-1,j : i+1,j : i,j-1 : i,j+1))`
In this way you might need to put some checks on index value to avoid undefined behaviour.

Comment: C has no exceptions. It has no checks on the index of the array going past the end. However, it may cause undefined behavior.

Comment: @Tan_007 updated it bro. I know C gives garbage values if variable value is undefined. Just the word to make it clear.

Comment: I did some changes. I also pasted the whole code, so that you understand better what I am trying to do.. TY all again for your help!!